# React Native Input loses focus after entering 1 letter

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue where when entering text into an input field it loses focus after one keystroke. From what I have read so far I think this is down to the form being re-rendered after each keystroke, but at present I am unsure on how to fix.

For my situation it's a sign up form, where a user selects whether they sign up as a company or a regular user.

For this I have created two forms, then use a ternary operator to decide which one to display (the user clicks a button to select, this selection is saved in a state).

```
export const SignUp = ({navigation}) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [clubFirstName, setClubFirstName] = useState('');
  const [clubFormSelected, setClubFormSelected] = useState(true);

  const SignUpClubForm = () => {
    return (
      <FormControl>
        <FormControl.Label>First Name</FormControl.Label>
          <Input
            id="clubFirstName"
            value={clubFirstName}
            onChangeText={clubFirstName => setClubFirstName(clubFirstName)}
          />
      </FormControl>
    )
  }

  const SignUpUserForm = () => {
    return (
      // User sign up form 
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormData({
      clubFirstName,
    });
  }, [clubFirstName]);

  return (
    <VStack space={3} mt="5">
      {clubFormSelected ? <SignUpClubForm /> : <SignUpUserForm />}
    </VStack>
  )
}
```

I suspect I have done something wrong with the rendering of the forms: is it that SignUpClubForm is re-rendered on every key stroke?

Comment: Can you add the code of the forms, something is wrong there

Comment: Have updated, also looking further into it, my `useEffect()` is having a knock on effect with my re renders I guess?

Comment: Yes, it rerenders and loses focus. You can try to wrap your Forms in a useCallback. If thats not working make a simple test with just a input and then slowly work your way up to find out where exactly its failing. I feel like the problem is that on every textChange your const SignUpClubForm and the other are getting rerendered. If you would just hardcode them in the return statement it would probably work 2 but wrapping these constants with a useCallback might be the cleaner looking solution

Comment: Yeah, maybe just a function to update clubFirsName and and formData will be good, instead of useEffect.

Comment: That useEffect seems fked up xD. If you need the Form for some action just build it onClick from the useStates

Comment: Other thing that would work is putting the clubFirstName State into the component const SignUpCLubForm. But if you need to use the const outside thats not an option

Comment: @Sumsidum Ill have a read up on useCallback first (still learning react native), not sure how that useCallBack would look with my setup at the moment...thank you for taking the time to answer though

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback